# React Disclaimer Page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have a disclaimer page. This is shown only once to the user. When user clicks continue, they accept the terms and shouldn’t be shown again to them.

By clicking CONTINUE button on this page I have to update showDisclaimer state variable to FALSE and navigate to ‘/react/nectPage’. There is no back button on this page and user shouldn’t be allowed to access this page via browser back button as well. What would be the right hook to use.  or

```
[if someCondition evaluate to true, then showDisclaimer is true, else false]
let showDisclaimer = useMemo(() => ( someCondition), [someCondition]);
const handleDisclaimer = () => {
        showDisclaimer = false;
        <Redirect to='/react/nextPage' />
    };
```

Comment: Are you storing a flag like "readDisclaimer" at backend? If yes, you can use that flag to allow / redirect from there.

Comment: If your question is about how to make the user navigate without being able to push the back button, set the `push` attribute to `false` on the `<Redirect />`.

Comment: Or if you don't want to do that way, you can store this flag in local storage and read it from there to determine if you should show this page or not.

Comment: I don't have this flag set in backend

Comment: Don't you want to set the flag at backend? If yes, that's the way to do it. If not (I don't know why. Maybe it is a public web app. Doesn't require authentication etc) , then you can use local storage. I am missing full context of your react app. So, I told you these 2 options ( local storage, and backend).

Comment: If you used react-router-dom, you can put this "guard" at route level. Or 2nd option - you will do this guarding (check) in " Component Did Mount" (Equivalent useEffect hook)

Comment: @AjeetShah-- this page doesn't require authentication. I'm using react-router-dom

Comment: @AjeetShah -- is this how you are suggesting ? useEffect(() => {let showDisclaimer = useMemo(() => ( someCondition), [someCondition])}, [someCondition])

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: @AjeetShah     const handleDisclaimer = () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('disclaimer', 'agreed');
        setShowDisclaimer(false);
        window.location.href = routes.NEXT_PAGE;
       }/>
    };
    const agreed = sessionStorage.getItem('disclaimer');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const handleDisclaimer = () => {
    sessionStorage.setItem('disclaimer', 'agreed');
    setShowDisclaimer(false);
    window.location.href = routes.NEXT_PAGE;
};
const agreed = sessionStorage.getItem('disclaimer');
```